# Why doesn't tris to quads preserve edge loops?

Tags: faces, edges

This always happens when I "de-triangularize" a mesh. Why? Is there a way to avoid it? Most of these edge loops are supposed to be near-vertical or near-horizontal.

[image]

Comment: because it's trying to make optimal quads that are relatively flat, so it wont be a exact opposite of triangulation

Comment: Interesting... Just checking, does "flat" mean perfectly within an "axis" plane, e.g. XY or XZ? I might have the wrong workflow for this (unless it's a common issue for humanoids; this is a back-skull), but I'd assume same horiz/vert edge loops are better.

Comment: flat means that the normal is uniform over the poly